# Node Alignment and Edge Labeling errors

Tags: graphviz

[Current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVe0c.png)
[Desired version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFmwh.jpg)

trying to recreate phase diagram in graphviz but I am unable fix three main issues:

1. Aligning all three nodes: solid, liquid, gas in a straigh line
2. Aligning edges vertically and clear corresponding to correct arrow
3. Expanding solid and gas node boxes so that sublimation and deposition edges can go straight down
   (if not possible makes sublimation and deposition edges bend at 90 twice to get back before getting back    to child nodes

Here is my code so far:
[current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTBY6.png)

```
digraph phase_change{
    graph [splines = ortho]
    node [shape = box]
    1 [label = "Solid"]
    2 [label = "Liquid"]
    3 [label = "Gas"]
    1 -> 2 [label = "Melting"]
    2 -> 1 [label = "Freezing"]
    1 -> 3 [label = "Sublimation"]
    3 -> 1 [label = "Deposition"]
    2 -> 3 [label = "Vaporization"]
    3 -> 2 [label = "Condensation"]
}
```

Comment: please include your code as text, not as an image

Answer (score 0):

1. The "best" way to guarantee vertical alignment of the three nodes is to place them all on the same rank (see below)
2. Not sure exactly what you are wanting w/ #2, but the "best" way to get straight-line edges is `splines=false`, `splines=ortho` should also work (though there are bugs in the ortho code that would probably cause poor results with this graph).  But both **splines** settings seem to be hitting this bug https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1844.  (see more below)
3. Explicitly setting **width** attribute for the nodes you want wider will accomplish what you want.

Below is a modified version of your graph that gets pretty close to your desired result.  Unfortunately, it requires an extra step to generate the desired result.  Because of the above mentioned bug, the **dot** output creates (curved) splines instead of the desired straight edges.  But running the **dot** output through **neato** (note the `-n` option) will then replace the splines with straight lines.  Ugh.

`dot  myFile.gv | neato -n -Tpng >myFile.png`

```
digraph phase_change{
    graph [splines = ortho]
    rankdir=LR
    nodesep=1.5    // all nodes on same rank

  {rank=same
    node [shape = box]
    3 [label = "Gas" width=4]
    2 [label = "Liquid" width=2.2]
    1 [label = "Solid" width=4]
  }

  3->1[xlabel=Deposition]
  2->1[xlabel=Freezing]
  3->2[xlabel=Condensation]

  edge[constraint=false]
  1->3[xlabel=Sublimation]
  1->2[xlabel=Melting]
  2->3[xlabel=Vaporization]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

- **neato -n** - https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords
- It might be possible to get the desired result in one **dot** pass by using multi-cell html-like nodes and ports. (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)
- Graphviz really struggles this this simple diagram.  Pikchr (https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md) might be a better tool in this case.